# Double slash in url after domain name [Kohana]

Tags: .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, kohana

I have a problem with URLs in Kohana framework.

When I type `mydomain.xyz/admin` that redirect to `mydomain.xyz//admin` and return some errors from Kohana core.

Here is a part of my `.htacces`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond $1 ^(index\.php|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico|media)
RewriteRule ^(?:application|modules|system)\b.* index.php/$0 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?kohana_uri=$1 [L]

###### Add trailing slash (optional) ######
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/[^\.]+[^/]$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1/ [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^(.*)public_html/index.php/(.*)$ http://mysite.xyz/$1$2 [R=301,L]
```

That problem has appeared after move site from other server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have it this way:

```
DirectorySlash Off
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

###### Add trailing slash (optional) ######
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !POST
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+[^/])$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [L,R=301,NE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !POST
RewriteRule ^(.*)public_html/index.php/(.*)$ /$1$2 [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteCond $1 ^(index\.php|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico|media)
RewriteRule ^(?:application|modules|system)\b.* index.php/$0 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?kohana_uri=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Make sure to clear your browser cache before testing this change.

Comment: I tried. That doesn't work. When I type `mysite.xyz`, that redirect it to `mysite.xyz//` and give error: `ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS`.

Comment: Okey, hard clear cache helped. But now appeared other error: when I in admin page type login and password, that don't go next. Page is only reloading. In browser console I see log: `Failed to clear temp storage: It was determined that certain files are unsafe for access within a Web application, or that too many calls are being made on file resources. SecurityError`.
Before do change in .htaccess, when I was manualy removing second slash that was working.

Comment: Ok, that works. Thanks o lot! :) 
So only Ctrl+Shift+R (ex. Google Chrome) refresh doesn't help?

Comment: Yes browser behave differently even on same browser on different OS.